# Determine whether Width or Height or Both is changed on Resize?

Tags: vb.net, resize

I am trying to make a proportional resizing for my form, so I need to know for each resize, what exactly was resized - width, height or both. How do I take that information from the `System.EventArgs` parameter?

Comment: You take it from Me.Size instead.  The old size is the previous value of this property, just store it.

Answer (score 1):

For proportinal resizing of child controls on a form, you should better use a native .NET control called [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) - this way you can avoid a lot of manual coding. Otherwise you could use [`Me.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.size%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and write something like this:

```
Dim _oldSize As Size
Dim _allowScaling As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  '[...] perform initial setup of your controls
  _oldSize = Me.Size
  _allowScaling = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
  If Not _allowScaling Then Exit Sub

  Dim deltaSize As Size = Me.Size - _oldSize
  Dim deltaWidth As Integer = Math.Abs(deltaSize.Width)
  Dim deltaHeight As Integer = Math.Abs(deltaSize.Height)

  If deltaWidth > 0 And deltaHeight > 0 Then
    'both width and height have changed
  ElseIf deltaWidth > 0 Then
    'width has changed
  ElseIf deltaHeight > 0 Then
    'height has changed
  End If

  _oldSize = Me.Size
End Sub
```